# How to declare an object in C++ that has a Class Data from another class with constructor with parameters

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I'm creating a simple object... but

I can't find a "semantic way" to create an object that has a Class as data with constructor, so I can't create my object ie:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Coordinate
{
public:
    Coordinate(int axisX,int axisY) {
        x= axisX;
        y= axisY;
    }
    int x,y;
};

class Point
{
public:
    string color;
    Coordinate coordinate;
};

int main()
{

    Point myPoint; //Error here also tried Point myPoint(1,1) or myPoint::Coordenate(1,1) etc...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the error is due to the fact that instantiating a "Point" will also instantiate a "Coordinate" object. But the default parameterless constructor for "Coordinate" is no longer available when you declare another constructor with parameters; so you need to either provide the values for the constructor(as described in the answers), or specifically declare a parameterless constructor for "Coordinate"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide a constructor for `Point` that does the initialization of the `coordinate` member appropiately:

```
class Point
{
  //make data members private!
  string color;
  Coordinate coordinate;
public:
  Point()
    : color("red")     //initialize color
    , coordinate(4,13) //initialize coordinate
  {}

  // and/or:
  Point(int x, int y, std::string clr = "")
    : color(clr)
    , coordinate(x,y)
  {}
};
```

You might want to look up constructor initialization lists (the part between the colon and the opening brace), as they could be new to you. Your `Coordinate` constructor could benefit from an initialization list, too:

```
class Coordinate
{
public:
   Coordinate(int axisX,int axisY) 
     : x(axisX), y(axisY)
   {}

private:
  //again, data members should be private in most cases
  int x,y;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to use an initialization list in `Point`'s constructor in order to construct `Coordinate` using the convert constructor you defined:

```
class Point
{
public:
  Point()
  :
    coordinate (42, 42) // you would somehow pass these to Point's constructor
  {
  }
};
```

The reason for this is because `Coordinate` doesn't have a default constructor (eg a constructor that can be called with no arguments).  Normally if you don't define a default constructor, the compiler will write one for you but this doesn't happen if you define *any* other constructor.

You could also modify the convert constructor you've already written to be a default constructor, by specifying default arguments:

```
Coordinate(int axisX = 42, int axisY = 42) {
  x = axisX;
  y = axisY;
}
```

However I'm not sure if this makes sense semantically in your program.

You could also implement a default constructor for `Coordinate`:

```
class Coordinate
{
public:
  Coordinate ()
  :
    x (0) ,
    y (0)
  { 
  }
  // ...
};
```

But then you have an issue where might you instantiate a `Coordinate` object with valid but nonsensical values for `x` and `y`.

Probably the best approach is the first one I've suggested, with a modification so that you pass the coordinates in to `Point`'s constructor:

```
class Point
{
public:
  Point (int x, int y)
  :
    coordinate (x, y)
  {
  }
};
```

This would be constructed thusly:

```
int main()
{
  Point p(1,2);
}
```

And it now becomes impossible to instantiate a `Point` object with an invalid or nonsensical `Coordinate`.

Answer (score -3):

```
class Point
{
public:
point(int axisX,int axisY):Coordinate(axisX,axisY);
string color;
Coordinate coordinate;
};
```

Comment: This won't compile since you are missing the constructor body. And without any explanation it won't help the OP much.